# Why does \cite work but \citep and \ref do not?

Tags: bibtex, citing, makefile

I'm using a Makefile that was working which looks:

```
# partly autogenerated, that's why it's so ugly!

# say 'make V=1' to see the full build output
ifndef V
Q = @
Q_LATEX = sh -c 'echo -e "   " `echo $$(basename "$$0") | tr a-z A-Z`"\t$${!\#/..\/..\//}"; ! "$$0" "$$@" | grep -A5 -E "^[^ ]+:[0-9]+:"'
Q_OTHER = sh -c 'echo -e "   " `echo $$(basename "$$0") | tr a-z A-Z`"\t$${!\#/..\/..\//}"; "$$0" "$$@" >/dev/null'
endif

LATEX = latex
PDFLATEX = pdflatex
BIBTEX = bibtex
DVIPS = dvips
DVIPDF = dvipdf
PDFTOEPS = pdftops -eps
PDFTOPS = pdf2ps
EPSTOPDF = epstopdf
FIGTODEV = fig2dev
MPOST = mpost

.PHONY: all clean archive

all:  thesis

texfiles = $(wildcard *.tex)

.PHONY: thesis
thesis: thesis.pdf thesis.ps

thesis.pdf: $(texfiles) thesis.bbl
    $(Q) rm -rf build/pdf/; mkdir -p build/pdf/
    $(Q) cd build/pdf/ && TEXINPUTS="../../:$$TEXINPUTS" $(Q_LATEX) $(PDFLATEX) -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error ../../thesis.tex
    $(Q) cd build/pdf/ && TEXINPUTS="../../:$$TEXINPUTS" $(Q_LATEX) $(PDFLATEX) -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error ../../thesis.tex
    $(Q) ln -f build/pdf/thesis.pdf thesis.pdf

thesis.dvi: $(texfiles) thesis.bbl
    $(Q) rm -rf build/dvi/; mkdir -p build/dvi/
    $(Q) cd build/dvi/ && TEXINPUTS="../../:$$TEXINPUTS" $(Q_LATEX) $(LATEX) -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error ../../thesis.tex
    $(Q) cd build/dvi/ && TEXINPUTS="../../:$$TEXINPUTS" $(Q_LATEX) $(LATEX) -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error ../../thesis.tex
    $(Q) ln -f build/dvi/thesis.dvi thesis.dvi

thesis.ps: thesis.dvi
    $(Q)$(Q_OTHER) $(DVIPS) -q thesis

thesis.aux: $(texfiles)
    $(Q) $(Q_LATEX) $(LATEX) -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error thesis.tex

thesis.bbl: thesis.aux
$(Q)$(Q_OTHER) $(BIBTEX) thesis

clean:
    rm -rf build/
    rm -f *.aux
    rm -f thesis.dvi thesis.idx thesis.ind thesis.ilg thesis.out thesis.toc thesis.pdf thesis.log thesis.bbl

archive: thesis-template.zip

thesis-template.zip: *.tex Makefile ETHlogo.* refs.bib
    mkdir -p thesis
    cp `git ls-files "*.tex" Makefile "ETHlogo.*" refs.bib` thesis/
    perl -i -pe 's/\$$VERSION\$$/'"$$(git describe)/" thesis/*.tex
    rm -f thesis-template.zip
    zip -r thesis-template.zip thesis/
```

This is an `example.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]
{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}


\begin{document}
\section{Reference}

\citep{Feller}

\cite{Feller}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{apa}
%\bibliography{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

And the generated `refs.bib` from endnote:

```
@BOOK{Feller,
   author = {Feller, William},
   title = {An introduction to probability theory and its applications},
   publisher = {Wiley},
   address = {New York,},
   series = {Wiley mathematical statistics series},
   note = {50008529
diagrs. 24 cm.
Vol. 2 has series: Wiley series in probability and mathematical statistics.
Bibliographical footnotes. "Some books on cagnate subjects": v. 2, p. 615-616.},
   keywords = {Probabilities.},
   year = {1950},
   type = {Book}
}
```

If I try to use `\ref{label}` BibTex doesn't create the updated `.bbl` file, even after deleting all files by hand.

Using `\citep{label}` BibTex creates the `.bbl`, I get ?? as a reference in my document.

If I use `\cite{label}` BibTex creates the `.bbl` file and I get the reference in my bibliography, but I don't see the reference in my document.

Now If I use `TexWorks` and `\cite{label}` I have to run `pdfLatex` 3 times `BibTex` once and `pdfLatex` again to create the reference, but `\citep{label}` doesn't work. I have no idea how to make `\ref{label}` work.

Comment: `\ref{label}` is to reference to internal counters, for sections or figures. It will never work with bib-entries.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why `\citep{label}` won't work?... Also let me know if you can comment on the make file

Comment: The Makefile is irrelevant. A minimal example of LaTeX code is needed.

Comment: Maybe you need something like `\usepackage{natbib}`? `\citep` is not a standard LaTeX command as far as I know.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. You need to post an MWE which can be used to reproduce the problem you are asking about. I ran `pdflatex` then `bibtex` then `pdflatex` then `pdflatex` and everything got resolved fine.

Comment: I would prefer `latexmk` over that makefile any time.

Comment: Your example shows the expected output, everything works fine. Please note, that you are using the wrong quote-marks.